# Why couldn't someone use the killing curse on Voldemort to get more time?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, avada-kedavra

Since Voldemort had his soul in different objects/animals, he couldn't be killed by 'Avada Kedavra'. But would the killing curse have at least destroyed his body temporarily, like at Godric's Hollow? If yes then why couldn't have someone used that to destroy him temporarily to get more time to find the horcruxes and destroy them?

Comment: I think that is why we don't see Voldemort much in the books- He is hiding out somewhere so nobody can do that.

Comment: Isn't it established that only the bad guys can (reliably) use Avada Kedavra?

Comment: There's some comprehensive info here https://www.quora.com/Why-did-the-horcruxes-need-to-be-destroyed-before-Voldemort-could-be-attacked on why Dumbledore didn't want Voldemort killed before the horcruxes were destroyed. I'm not posting as an answer because this is in no way my work and I don't want to be taking credit.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is not using Avada Kedavra against the Dark Lord, the issue is facing the Dark Lord.

Almost in every depiction in the books, Voldemort is described as the greatest dark wizard of all times, him only really being matched by (and fearing)  Dumbledore.

Note though, even in the fight between them in the Ministry of Magic, they are evenly matched and the fight comes to an end only when Aurors start to appear making him flee.

We don’t have a lot of canon information on direct confrontations by Voldemort but Dumbledore power is pretty well established in the Order of Phoenix when he first establishes he’d easily scape Azkban to follow with easily overpowering several Aurors, including Kingsley.

That means basically almost no one is a match for Voldemort. Aurors are allowed to use the killing curse after *The Order of the Phoenix* and they probably do, but the fact remains that, anyone that meets Voldemort, save Harry or Dumbledore, ends up dead... whether it uses the killing course or not.

Answer (score 3):

There are many spells one could have used on the Dark Lord to impede him but to answer your question: it's very hard to conjure Avada Kevadra, you literally have to be willing to kill somebody for the spell to even come to be.

Of course the question is "if someone did Avada Voldemort, would it stop him?"

Well the thing is, Avada Kevadra wasn't the spell that destroyed Voldemort's body at Godric's Hollow, it was instead a protection spell bound by emotion.

So my answer is, I don't know.

Comment: There are probably enough people willing to kill him, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: the thing that killed Voldemort in Godric's Hollow was the Avada Kedavra. the protection spell was the thing that caused it to backfire.